# is it possible to send bits of data between two android mobiles over internet without a server?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application, in this I have a requirement. Data needs to be transferred between two android mobiles, the data is very small in bits.

I want to transfer data over internet, my doubts are:

Is it possible to do it without a server, like we send MMS without a server.

In my app data will be sent with the SMS, that data is attached to the SMS and transferred over internet

Comment: You cannot send MMS without the server of the provider. If you want to use SMS then you are done i would say. But SMS uses the server of the provider also. What are your questions? And SMS does not use internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes. It is possible. But it is tough to develop generic application. You can do the Simple test program in your lab.

Steps:

1. Write a Socket program and open a port 80.
2. Find the IP of your mobile.
3. Open browser and type the IP.
4. You will get whatever your server sends.

Pls. check the following link.

[Sample Android Client Server Program](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html)

Comment: it works like whatsapp but no need for storage of sent and received data. just receiver see the received data reads it and dismiss it.Transmission i need no need to store anything anywhere.

Comment: Pls. check this link. This will help. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, pls. don't forget to tick the answer and up-vote it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have you tried application  YO in that app no need to store or process big data my requirement is similar to that

Comment: Chris, i just gave an example. Irfan wants to explore how to make two devices talk without a server. Also http protocol can be hosted in any port. We are writing these kind of programs in our day-to-day life.